# Passing arrays to a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm fairly new to Java so please have some patience with me.

I was wondering how I could go about passing an array with a bunch of strings into a new method that would ask the user a question and then print the array. I then also want the input from the user to be stored in a different array but I feel confident I can do this part myself.

A fragment of what I think the code should look like is as follows:

```
public static void birdarray()
{
   String[] birds = {"Blue Tit", "Blackbrid", "Robin"};
}

public static void wanttogetarrayinhere ()
{
   String question = print("What bird are you reporting?");
   print(birds);
```

I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The methods needs to accept one parameter of type `String[]` (`String... ` would work as well, but you should understand [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) first).

Comment: public static void wanttogetarrayinhere (String[] birds) {}

Comment: Note: You'll need an overloaded `print` method since you are calling it on both a `String` and `String[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as a parameter:

```
public static void wanttogetarrayinhere(String[] arr)
{
    String question = print("What bird are you reporting?");
    print(arr);
}
```

Then pass in the desired array when you call it:

```
String[] birds = {"Blue Tit", "Blackbrid", "Robin"};
wanttogetarrayinhere(birds);
```

As was pointed out in the comments you'll also need an overloaded `print()` method, with an overload for a `String` parameter and one for a `String[]` parameter, e.g.:

```
public static void print(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

public static void print(String[] arr) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        builder.append(arr[i]);
        if (i<arr.length-1)
            builder.append(", ");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

Comment: And then make sure you correctly call the function: wanttogetarrayinhere(birds);

Comment: @PunDefeated good call to include that as well, edited my answer :)

Comment: @jonk That seems to get the job done in terms of passing the array - so thanks - but why would I get [Ljava.lang.String;@139a55 printed to my screen instead of the array?

Comment: that would probably be because you need a specific print method for a `String[]` parameter, added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to get the array into the method:

```
    public static void wanttogetarrayinhere(String[] input){
        // then to print array out something like:
        for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
         System.out.println(input[i]);
     }
    }
```